# How can I create a chart to show a possible pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have 3 columns in my table.

```
Date       Day of Week  # of hours

11/27/2013  Wednesday   7
2/4/2015    Wednesday   7
3/18/2015   Wednesday   7
5/2/2013    Thursday    2.5
5/15/2013   Wednesday   2.5
5/31/2013   Friday      1.5
6/26/2013   Wednesday   1
```

The goal is to show a chart that can show the following

1. Likeliness of an event occurring on Monday -> Friday
2. Likeliness of an event using 7 hours
3. Based on the data in the spreadsheet, a graph showing which # of hours is highest-> lowest

Comment: the data file is very long and has entries for years. I only provided a small subset of that data

Comment: Actually, I would argue this isn't an excel problem at all. I think what you are really asking is how to do event probability like http://pbadupws.nrc.gov/docs/ML0305/ML030580412.pdf so it is a mathmatics problem. Once you are able to do that then you can use a bar graph by day of the week based on your formulas for probability.

Comment: I just have the data. I don't know where to start. I never use Excel for anything. I want to use statistics (not probability). Isn't probability the trying to determine an event in the future. Maybe I'm wrong but I want to show a chart on past events

Comment: Do you only have the 3 columns?

Comment: I added a 4th Column to show the Type of activity being done. For example, WORK, DRIVING, ETC

Comment: OK, then either work on building a probability model or ask Mathmatics... Then you can work on graphing useful datapoints.

Comment: You're going to have to figure out the math and how you want to visualize the data first. Once you have that, you can ask about how to implement/visualize your well-defined analysis in Excel. But for now, it's not clear what exactly you want to do, and your request is overly broad for Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For # 1 of your question you could use countifs to determine how often (in the past) the event occured on each day of the week. For example, you would count the number of days an event occurred on a monday and divide over the total count.

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,"Monday")/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,"<>""")
```

Monday  0
Tuesday 0
Wednesday   71%
Thursday    14%
Friday  14%

You could then use the data to create your chart. You could the same logic to answer #2.